# Get attribute from record

Tags: c#, reflection, record

I'm looking for a way to get the attribute defined on a record constructor "field".

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var property = typeof(TestRecord)
               .GetProperties()
               .First( x => x.Name == nameof(TestRecord.FirstName) );

var attr0 = property.Attributes; // NONE
var attr1 = property.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(DisplayAttribute), true ); // empty

var property1 = typeof(TestRecord)
                .GetProperties()
                .First( x => x.Name == nameof(TestRecord.LastName) );

var attr2 = property1.Attributes; // NONE
var attr3 = property1.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(DisplayAttribute), true ); // Works

public sealed record TestRecord( [Display] String FirstName, [property: Display] String LastName );
```

I'm able to get the attribute on `LastName` targeting the property (using `property:`).

But I'm not able to find a way to retrieve the attribute on `FirstName`.

I'm sure there is a way to read the attribute data... at least ASP.NET is able to read validation and display attributes specified without targeting the property (`property:`).

Comment: @Dai Why are you editing perfectly valid and compiling C# code? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates

Comment: Because your `record` type was buried _below the fold_ in StackOverflow's scrolling code area, I couldn't see it at all at first, and you had inconsistent indenyation and didn't have the correct code-language hints in your post. Also, not everyone is using VS2022.

Comment: [Here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0ARAlgQwOYDsB7AZwBdMBjY1AYUIBMBTAQX2wBsBPYzYgbliwQAZkTFGHRvUQAnRhUIzpAFUZkASvMX0AFIliJDiAMqkZmfLkQAxTDLIA5bAFtGAGn0wjiANoPCpA4AruzsALomZhZWADLYji6MiACUfEA===) I have replaced your `DisplayAttribute` to `NotNullAttribute` (since `DataAnnotations` can't be used easily in sharplab). If you look at the decompiled code then you can see that this attribute is used only inside constructor but not at the property itself.

Comment: If you want to place the attribute on the generated property, use `[property: Display] string FirstName`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place: when using the "braceless" `record` syntax in C#, attributes placed on members are actually **parameter attributes**.

You can get the `DisplayAttribute` from `[Display] String FirstName` like so:

```cs
ParameterInfo[] ctorParams = typeof(TestRecord)
    .GetConstructors()
    .Single()
    .GetParameters();
        
DisplayAttribute firstNameDisplayAttrib = ctorParams
    .Single( p => p.Name == "FirstName" )
    .GetCustomAttributes()
    .OfType<DisplayAttribute>()
    .Single();
```